# PHP not getting values inside if statement using GET

Tags: php, html

In my code, I am trying to get values of variables from one php to another. In this php file I am getting values from some other php file through url.

I got all the values inside else part but not inside if, the variable meeting_id and pemail are not storing any thing in the database and all the other fields are storing values perfectly. Where am I wrong?

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['send'])) { 

    $pemail = $_POST['e'];
    $meeting_id = $_POST['mid']; 
    $date = $_POST["dat"];
    if ($date=="val1") {
        $d1 = 'Yes';
    } 
    else {
        $d1='No';
    }
    if ($date=="val2") {
        $d2 = 'Yes';
    }
    else {
        $d2='No';
    }
    $location = $_POST["location"];
    if ($location=="val1") {
        $l1 = 'Yes';
    }
    else {
        $l1='No';
    }
    if ($location=="val2") {
        $l2 = 'Yes';
    }
    else {
        $l2='No';
    }
    $check_list1 = $_POST['check_list1'];
    if ($check_list1 != 'yes') {
        $check_list1 = 'No';
    }
    $check_list2 = $_POST['check_list2'];
    if ($check_list2 != 'yes') {
        $check_list2 = 'No';
    }
    $host='mysql5.000webhost.com';
    $uname='admin';
    $pwd='*****';

    $db="meeting";
    $con = mysql_connect($host,$uname,$pwd) or die("connection failed");
    mysql_select_db($db,$con) or die("db selection failed");
    $flag['code']=0;
    if($r=mysql_query("insert into meeting.response (meeting_id, Email, 
     DAT1, DAT2, Location1, Location2, Travel, Hotel) 
     values('$meeting_id','$pemail','$d1','$d2','$l1','$l2','$check_list1',
     '$check_list2') ",$con))

        {

            $flag['code']=1;
            echo"hi";
        }
    print(json_encode($flag));
    mysql_close($con);

    ?> 
    Your response was sent
        <?php 
        } else {
    $top=$_GET['t']; 
    $dat1=$_GET['d1']; 
    $tim1=$_GET['t1']; 
    $dat2=$_GET['d2']; 
    $tim2=$_GET['t2']; 
    $loc1=$_GET['l1']; 
    $loc2=$_GET['l2'];
    $mid=$_GET['id']; 
    $e=$_GET['pemail']; 
    ?> 
    <h1><center>Meeting Invitation</center></h1>
    <form action="my.php" method="post">
    You are invited for the meeting on <?php echo $top; ?>
    proposed dates are :<br><br>
    Date &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Time<br>
    <?php echo $dat1; ?> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <?php echo $tim1; ?><input 
    type = "radio" name = "dat" <?php if (isset($dat) && $dat=="val1") echo 
                                                                           "checked";?> value = "val1" checked="true" ><br>
    <?php echo $dat2; ?> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <?php echo $tim2; ?><input 
    type = "radio" name = "dat" <?php if (isset($dat) && $dat=="val2") echo 
                                                                           "checked";?> value = "val2" ><br><br>
    Proposed locations are :<br>
    Location 1 : &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <?php echo $loc1; ?> <input type = 
                                                                "radio" name = "location" <?php if (isset($location) && 
                                                                                                    $location=="val1") echo 
                                                                                                                           "checked";?>  value = "val1" checked="true" ><br>
    Location 2 : &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <?php echo $loc2; ?> <input type = 
                                                                "radio" name = "location" <?php if (isset($location) && $location=="val2")          
                                                                echo 
                                                                    "checked";?>  value = "val2" ><br><br>
    Do you want travel facility ? &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_list1" value="yes"> <br><br>
    Do you want hotel facility ? &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_list2" value="yes"> <br><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="Send Response">
    <input type="reset" >
    </form>

    <?php 
}; 
?>
```

Comment: When you use `GET`, the parameters are in `$_GET`, but you're using `$_POST['mid']`.

Comment: If you want to be able to get parameters either through GET or POST, you can use `$_REQUEST` -- it combines them.

Comment: I dont see you adding the inputs e, mid, to the form...

Comment: @satchcoder i don't need these inputs in form, i need to store these values in database

Comment: @Barmar i just used $_GET but its still not working

Comment: have you tried to find out what has been sent to your page, with help of print_r as i supposed?

Comment: all the values are sent correctly to this page but not inside if part

Answer (score 1):

You are passing variables with POST not GET.  For bonus I cleaned up your code for readability.

**In your code change this:**

```
Your response was sent
<?php 
} else {
$top=$_GET['t']; 
$dat1=$_GET['d1']; 
$tim1=$_GET['t1']; 
$dat2=$_GET['d2']; 
$tim2=$_GET['t2']; 
$loc1=$_GET['l1']; 
$loc2=$_GET['l2'];
$mid=$_GET['id']; 
$e=$_GET['pemail']; 
?>
```

**TO THIS:**

```
Your response was sent
<?php 
} else {
$top=$_POST['t'].'<br>'; 
$dat1=$_POST['d1'].'<br>'; 
$tim1=$_POST['t1'].'<br>'; 
$dat2=$_POST['d2'].'<br>'; 
$tim2=$_POST['t2'].'<br>'; 
$loc1=$_POST['l1'].'<br>'; 
$loc2=$_POST['l2'].'<br>';
$mid=$_POST['id'].'<br>'; 
$e=$_POST['pemail']; 
?>
```

Comment: i have changed my code according to yours but its still not working

Answer (score 0):

You say you sent your values via url, not via a post action. So $_POST is empty, use $_GET for url values.
Check what you send by displaying the values like: print_r($_GET) and print_r($_POST).